# Change post featured image

Tags: css

I would like to you ask you. I changed the dimensions of the thumbnail size in my theme. But in the categories, it looks stretched (I mean the images associate with a post in the category view). Problem is that some pictures are in landscape and others are in portrait format. The picture is not visible in full resolution. Is there any CSS command which can help me? What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Using `background-size: cover` instead of  `background-size: contain` with a custom [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) ? It will cut images but preserve the same format/size for all.